# WP_User_Query with meta_query array relation 'OR'

Tags: meta-query, wp-user-query

I just updated to WP 4.1 and a User_Query I was using is now returning 0 instead of the expected results.

```
$pm = array(
    //'role' => 'program_manager',
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => $staff_role,
            'value' => 'program_manager',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $staff_role,
            'value' => 'administrator',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

This function was inserted into a `new WP_User_Query()` to return all users who have a custom role of `Program Manager` or `Administrator` which was then subsequently displayed on a page. If I remove the `meta_query` and simply query the `program_manager` role then it works fine, but I still need to include the administrator in this count. What has changed?

Comment: Is the commenting out of the `role` key/value pair intentional?

Comment: Yes, fully intentional. I simply left that there from an earlier version of the variable. I could essentially remove that entirely but kept it for a reminder to myself.

For additional clarification, I use the variable here in the following `WP_User_Query` :

`$program_manager = new WP_User_Query( $pm );`

and run the following loop to display the results:

`foreach ( $program_manager->results as $user )`

Comment: Have you turned on [error logs / debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to make sure there's no syntax changes or helpful warnings?

Comment: Also, could you expand on what `$staff_role` is and how it's set, maybe that is being overwritten somewhere so that it returns unexpected results.

Comment: There's nothing in the debug log that indicates a potential problem related to this (that I can see anyway)
$staff_role is defined below:
`if( is_array($user->role) == true){ 
  $staff_role=esc_attr(implode(", ",$user->role));
  } else {$staff_role=$user->role;};`

Comment: Even if the `results` property of `WP_User_Query` is `public` (just poor design), please use `->get_results()` instead. Also it's enough to question `is_array( $thing )` as this will evaluate to `true/false` anyway, which means you can leave the loose type comparison `== true` off as this makes it actually worse and would match a string as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the Codex:
[Multiple custom user fields handling](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    0 => array(
        'key'     => 'country',
        'value'   => 'Israel',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    1 => array(
        'key'     => 'age',
        'value'   => array( 20, 30 ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
)
);
```

Try adding the 0 => array and 1 => array

Comment: This makes no difference in the output. So as you can see in the $staff_role, there are some users who have multiple roles, thus the reason I am using the LIKE comparison