# Display Users from two roles in one list

Tags: meta-query, wp-user-query

I asked a question a few days ago ([link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174642/wp-user-query-with-meta-query-array-relation-or)) about a problem I encountered with WP 4.1 and a `WP_User_Query` I ran with a custom meta array. My current code worked until I upgraded to 4.1:

```
    if( is_array($user->role) == true){ 
    $staff_role=esc_attr(implode(", ",$user->role));
    } else {$staff_role=$user->role;};

    $pm = array(
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => $staff_role,
                            'value' => 'program_manager',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            ),
                        array(
                            'key' => $staff_role,
                            'value' => 'administrator',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            )
                    )
    );
// User Queries
    $program_manager = new WP_User_Query( $pm );
// User Counts
    $pm_count = count($program_manager->results);
// User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $program_manager->results ) ) {
        echo '<h2>Program Managers (' . $pm_count . ')</h2>';
        foreach ( $program_manager->results as $user ) {
            echo '<li>',
            pods_user_profile_display($user);
            echo '</li><div class="clearboth"></div><br />';
    }
    echo '<hr />';
    } else {
    echo '<h2>Program Managers</h2>No managers found.';
    }
```

However, I didn't get an answer.

Hopefully this new question will get an answer:

I want to display a list of WP users with the role "Administrator" or "Program Manager" in a directory on my website. For example, I have 1 `administrator` and 12 `program_manager`s. I want the list to display all 13 users sorted by `display_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the roles for a user are stored in (dbprefix)_capabilities, I'd try grabbing the database prefix and then using it to grab people with the right capabilities (caps are in a serialized array):

```
global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$meta_name = "{$prefix}capabilities";

'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => "{$meta_name}"
                        'value' => 'program_manager',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                    array(
                        'key' => "{$meta_name}",
                        'value' => 'administrator',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                )
);
```

The above should give you all users that are program managers or administrators.

The thing I see that may have broken your code is as follows:

```
if( is_array($user->role) == true){ 
    # This will break your meta query as it could create "subscriber, administrator" as a key
    # and your meta query does 'key' => $staff_role
    $staff_role=esc_attr(implode(", ",$user->role));
} else {
    $staff_role=$user->role;
}
```

The second a user gets a second role, the query starts looking for a key value that contains comma separated roles. Of course, maybe that is what you seek, but I'd double check in the database as such a key would be a bit odd.

Comment: Thank you @Privateer. In order to reach my desired outcome, I converted the `meta_query` back into a variable and added the `'order_by'=>'display_name'` before feeding it into the `WP_User_Query`